# How to derive the Fisher information in the laplace approximation of a generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, references, spatial, fisher-information, laplace-approximation

I am currently using the Laplace approximation to fit some geostatistical models for binomial data. Regarding parameters estimation I do not have any problem. I can easily implement the Laplace approximation and get my estimates.

But when it comes to obtain the standard errors I am puzzled about how I can derive the hessian of my objective function, hence the Fisher information. I tried to derive this analytically but it seems very laborious and tedious. Is there any reference about this or someone has a solution?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Emanuele Giorgi! You can refer to "Maximum Likelihood for Generalized Linear Models With Nested Random Effects via High-Order, Multivariate Laplace Approximation" by RAUDENBUSMH, YANG, and YOSEF (2000). Also, the `glmer()` in `R` package `lme4` uses Laplacian approximation in default.

Comment: Can you just use a finite-difference approximation to get a good-enough estimate of the hessian ... ?

Comment: You should really give some more details, like the exact method you are using (or at least a reference)